# How are hashtables implemented in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hash

Some languages implement hash tables which can use anything, not just strings, as a key. In JavaScript, you are restricted to strings and numbers. Is the lookup for this kind  of implementation still O(1)? Is there an implementation in JavaScript?

Comment: can you clarify what you meant by "Hash Objects"?  Were you referring to the client side `new Object(); or var foo = {};` type of object or the underlying data structure used by "the system" (e.g. C++)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's obviously a lot of misunderstanding around this subject.  In JavaScript, they keys of objects are actually **only strings** (see [§8.10](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.10)).  *Anything* (including numbers) used as an object key is converted to string.  Thus, `obj[1]` and `obj["1"]` **are equivalent**.

Internally, many JS implementations use some kind of hash table to enable quick lookup of object properties.  V8 actually [generates hidden C++ classes](https://developers.google.com/v8/design#prop_access) that allows lookups to execute in a single CPU instruction.  Either way, it's safe to assume that object property access is fast and near O(1).

As a consequence of all object property keys being converted to string, you can only use things that convert to string as a key.  Since numbers naturally convert to string, they work fine.  Same for booleans.  Dates work too, since `Date` instances convert to unique strings (although there are edge cases to be aware of).

However, objects do not convert into meaningful strings.  For example:

```
var o = {};
o[{a:1}]='some value';
```

Actually results in:

```
o = { '[object Object]': 'some value' }
```

because of the [string conversion rules](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8).  Since every object converts to `[object Object]`, adding many objects as keys to another object will result in an object with only one property.

Of course, it's still possible to use an object as a key.  You just have to override the default implementation of `toString` — in effect, creating your own hashing algorithm.  For example,

```
function ComplexKey(a,b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

ComplexKey.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.a + ':' + this.b;
}

var o = {};
o[new ComplexKey(1,2)] = 'x';
o[new ComplexKey(3,4)] = 'y';
```

Results in:

```
o = {
    '1:2': 'x',
    '3:4': 'y'
}
```

Comment: Theorically could I use any object storing them as hash[JSON.toString(obj)]?

Comment: So long as the object doesn't have any circular references, yes.  (With `JSON.stringify`)

Comment: Thank you. Very informative answer. So could I expect constant lookup accessing a hash with thousands of keys generated by JSON.toString without any kind of bothering I'm unaware of?

Comment: [Lookup time is constant](http://jsperf.com/sl-object-lookup-time), but [there's a large difference in *key generation time*](http://jsperf.com/stringify-vs-custom-tostring) between `JSON.stringify` and using an object with a custom `toString`.  `JSON.stringify` is very slow.

Comment: Wow, very good. Thanks again.
On the edit, nice to know, too.

Comment: +1 For filling in the bit about implementing a custom to-string.

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript does not have "hashtables".

It has [Dictionaries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) which are collections of Key/Value pairs, with the restriction that a Key must be unique. The difference is that the implementation for a Dictionary does not imply a hash, although a [Hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) will likely be used internally by implementations for performance reasons.

All *objects* in JavaScript function as Dictionaries (this excluded primitive types such as `string` and `number`). Generally an empty object is used for a generic "hashtable":

```
var o = {};
o[propExpression] = valueExpression;
```

However, here is the important thing: **all property/key values are first converted to strings**.

Thus the following are identical:

```
o[true] = 1
o["true"] = 1
```

---

Following through the ECMAScript is a bit confusing, but the key part to "knowing" that property names are all strings is found in [Property Descriptors](http://es5.github.com/#property-identifier):

> The Property Identifier type is used to associate a property name with a Property Descriptor. Values of the Property Identifier type are pairs of the form (name, descriptor), *where name is a String* and descriptor is a Property Descriptor value.

Comment: Just wondering, is the functional difference between a "hashtable" and a dictionary the form in which the key is composed? What is the functional difference?

Comment: There is no implementation available?

Comment: @JaredFarrish A Dictionary can be implemented without a hashing function: e.g. just an sequence of key-value pairs. A Hashtable implies a hashing function. Internally implementations will likely use a Hashtable to back properties (perhaps even controlled with a limit). However, there is no provision for a "hash code" or ability for an object to specify such a hash function in the ECMAScript specification. Implementations would thus use an internally hashing function (for the string property names) if they choose to use a Hashtable.